# Sqlite3 List index out of range when trying to get LIKE Query

Tags: python, database, sqlite, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to execute the following code:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("./Databases/Functions/He.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

sql = "SELECT * FROM Requests WHERE Request like ?"
cursor.execute(sql, [(msg)])
results = cursor.fetchall()[0]
print results

if((results)[1] == "True"):
    GPIO = (results)[2]
    Direction = (results)[3]
    print "GPIO Setup ready.."
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
File "./Functions/doFunctions.py", line 29, in enRequests
results = cursor.fetchall()[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm always messing up with database, and finally fixing those problems,
I don't know why they pop up from the beginning..

The code getting msg string, searching if it exist on the database, if it does then taking the GPIO pin and sending signal (request is at index `0` in the database row while the GPIO pin is at index `2`).

Answer (score 1):

Your query returned 0 results, so there is no first row to fetch. `.fetchall()` returns an empty list in that case, and there is no item at index `0`.

If you are only interested in the first result of a query, you should really use [`.fetchone()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone) instead:

```
results = cursor.fetchone()
```

`.fetchone()` either returns the row, or `None` if there were no matching results.

You are using redundant parenthesis in your query; this is not the cause of your problem, but you can safely remove them:

```
cursor.execute(sql, [msg])
```

or use a tuple:

```
cursor.execute(sql, (msg,))
```

You do that in several places, you can cut out a lot of the `(...)` in your code without any effect other than improved readability. Adding in a test if there *are* results from the `.fetchone()` call your code could be:

```
if results and results[1] == "True":
    GPIO = results[2]
    Direction = results[3]
    print "GPIO Setup ready.."
```

Comment: But I entered the same string as in the database, how can it be that the program can find it in the database?

Comment: @DarkFoxxy: Without seeing your database and the contents of `msg`, that is impossible for me to say. The database doesn't think there is a match.